# Polynomial fit and uncertainty

Tags: error-analysis, statistics

I am trying to fit a polynomial function by least square method and I want to know the uncertainty on my fitting parameters.

Comment: This is off topic here, but you can check at [stats.SE] and see if it's already been asked there. (I suspect it has.)

Comment: I've got C++ code that does this, and I'd be happy for you to grab a copy if you want. Comment here if you want a copy and I'll post the URL.